# Subscribe/Unsubscribe friends in the news feed via api

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, feed

Some context:  I'm interested in building an app that allows a user to efficiently browse their friends list and subscribe or unsubscribe from their friends' posts.

Question:  Via any facebook api is there a way to programmatically unsubscribe a friend?  Similarly is there a way to programmatically subscribe a friend?  I'm unsure of the terminology, instead of subscribe/unsubscribe maybe I should substitute hide/unhide?  I'm specifically interested in performing this action for the person, not for a specific post.

This functionality exists for a user on their news feed and is described by facebook here:

[Facebook Help Center - How do I control what I see in my news feed?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=218728138156311)

Comment: I have not heard of that functionality within the API, nor even anything in the facebook's developers blog hinting about it.